# How to type logarithmic functions into Desmos graphing calculator?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

Does anyone know how to type logarithmic functions into Desmos graphing calculator (https://www.desmos.com/calculator) ?

I need to type a function, in which y equals to logorithm of 10 with the base of 5.

I tried:

y = log (5) x and y = log 5 (x), but neither one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here it is. Just click on the “functions” tab on the right hand side of the panel and scroll down.

EDIT FOR CLARITY: [image]
Look at the text box closely. First up, the cursor is positioned in the region where you want the base to be. So after clicking the $log_a$ button, immediately type 5 (if the cursor moves, click in the lower region between “log” and “(“.) Then click inside the brackets to put the argument in. The final thing is:[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand what is "a" there? Is that the base? How should I go about logarithm of 10 with the base of 5? If I click on that button I get "log ( )". How do I proceed from there?

Comment: Yes it is. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Edited for clarity @brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Press underscore: `l` `o` `g` `_` `5` `→` `(`